# Extracting ZAP report running in container on Jenkins agent (docker based)

Tags: zap

My setup is as follows:
Jenkins pipeline script which triggers Jenkins job which runs inside a dokcer container.
ZAP is in containerzied mode

Commands used:
`echo DEBUG - mkdir -p $PWD/out`
`mkdir -p $PWD/out`

```
echo DEBUG - chmod 777 $PWD/out
chmod 777 $PWD/out

test -d ${PWD}/out \
  && docker run -v $(pwd)/out:/zap/wrk/:rw -t owasp/zap2docker-live zap-api-scan.py -t $TARGET_URL -f openapi -d -r zap_scan_report.html
```

Also tried: `docker run --user $(id -u):$(id -g) -v $(pwd)/out:/zap/wrk/:rw -t owasp/zap2docker-live zap-api-scan.py -t $TARGET_URL -f openapi -d -r zap_scan_report.html`

Scan works fine but report is not in the "out" directory.

This works fine on a VM environment

Any suggestions as I guess the mount is not working in a docker container

Comment: Based on the details you provided you tried to mount an `/out` directory but then did not write the report there. Neither of your commands specified it's use for the report. `...openapi -d -r zap_scan_report.html`

Comment: so do you mean to suggest that it should be /$PWD/out/zap_scan_report.html

Comment: No you should use `/zap/wrk/zap_scan_report.html` since thats what you mounted insude the container (I believe)

Comment: It doesn't work. Same result